# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest returning all nil in Completion Block (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to ween myself off AFNetworking and use NSURLConnection from Swift. Although seemingly simple, I can't get this short block of code to return anything in the completion handler block. All three objects (response, data, error) are nil when I break within the completion handler block and po them in the console. It's definitely making the connection, as I can see it happen on the server end.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.0.5:8081/ac")
let urlR = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
let q = NSOperationQueue()

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlR, queue: q, completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

    })
```

I can't seem to find anyone else having this issue, and have found several examples of people successfully using what as far as I can see is exactly this code. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try calling `println` on them instead...po in Swift often just doesn't work

Comment: Thanks! `println()` doesn't seem to work in the lldb console, but i can call it from the code and as you suggested, the first two objects aren't actually nil at all, and I can work with the data object. That's pretty confusing though. Is there somewhere I **can** do `println()` whilst the code is stopped? Having to do all debugging output in the main code ahead of time seems like a step backwards if not.

Comment: Yes I meant for you to add it to your code. Currently Xcode 6 is in beta so its simply not working well...especially the debugging. I'm sure it will be working well in version 1.0 though. But yeah, I'm only able to debug using `println()` in the code.